# Acquiring results from a foreign key reference

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, key

I am trying to set up a database that will hold/maintain a set of user privileges. I am also using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have made a Accounts table, with the PK= UserId.

I have made a Profiles table with the PK=ProfileId

I Have made a UserPrivileges table using the following SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE UserPermissions 
(
    UserId int REFERENCES Accounts (UserId),
    ProfileId int REFERENCES Profiles (ProfileId),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId, ProfileId)
)
```

But when I execute a Select query from the UserPrivileges table, nothing is returned even though I do have a few entries in the 2 previous tables.

From my understanding of foreign keys, their values are taken from the referenced table. And since the referenced tables do have entries, why are none being entered into the UserPrivileges table?

Comment: do you have records in UserPermissions table?
Your pattern looks like UserPermission is a Master table where Accounts and Profiles are Details tables, if you dont have records in UserPermission table you can't run select query even you have records in two Details tables, for this scenario you need to use right right join in your query

Comment: I am trying to use UserPrivileges as a intersection/junction table to connect each user to a privileges profile

Comment: but whats the use of this i mean creating intersection table why dont you direct link Accounts and Profile table directly to each other  using foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key is just a reference. If doesn't mean that you don't need entries in your table. You need them! But these entries has also to exist in the related table. Here is a very good explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1):

First, you didn't create a UserPrivileges table. You created a UserPermissions table. (If we're to believe your code.)

Second, no rows are being entered in UserPermissions because you didn't insert any rows into UserPermissions. Foreign keys don't make rows appear as if by magic. *You* decide which rows belong in UserPermissions, and *you* insert them.

Comment: UserPermissions is what I meant I apologize.